# Order a list of GameObjects by position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to order a list of objects by their y-axis posistion. I have tried the following line:
`objectsInScene = objectsInScene.OrderBy(x => x.transform.position.y);`, but I receive the following error:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<UnityEngine.GameObject>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<UnityEngine.GameObject>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

All help is appreciated. I have pasted my script below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Linq;

public class spawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        List<GameObject> objectsInScene = new List<GameObject>();

        foreach (GameObject go in Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[])
        {
            if (!EditorUtility.IsPersistent(go.transform.root.gameObject) && 
                !(go.hideFlags == HideFlags.NotEditable ||
                  go.hideFlags == HideFlags.HideAndDontSave))
                objectsInScene.Add(go);
        }
        foreach (GameObject temp in objectsInScene){
            if (temp.tag == "Populate"){
                temp.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        objectsInScene = objectsInScene.OrderBy(x => x.transform.position.y);
        
        StartCoroutine(Example(objectsInScene));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try calling `ToList()`, as in

```
objectsInScene = objectsInScene.OrderBy(x => x.transform.position.y).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution:

```cs
objectsInScene.Sort((o, o1) => o.transform.position.y.CompareTo(o1.transform.position.y));
```

Comment: Well, yes, but you're going to have to call `ToList()` anyway to get the game objects into the list first.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No need. Game objects are defined inside the list. I tried without `ToList()` and it was correct.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The OP has already populated the list.